# freeing multidimensional array C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, memory-leaks

I have this struct called Grid that holds a 2d array of strings. I'v been searching on how to free multidimensional arrays properly and can't seem to find the problem with this procedure as valgrind keeps detecting errors and leaked memory. Thanks in advance!

```
  typedef struct Grid{
    int N;
    int M;
    char ***adj;
  }TGrid;

  TGrid* emptyGrid(int N, int M){
   int i,j;

   TGrid *Grid = malloc(sizeof(TGrid));
   Grid->N = N;
   Grid->M = M;
   Grid->adj = malloc(N * sizeof(char ***));

   for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
       Grid->adj[i] = malloc(M * sizeof(char **));
       for(j = 0; j < M; j++){
           Grid->adj[i][j] = malloc(10 * sizeof(char *));
       }
   }
   return Grid;
}


void freeGrid(TGrid *Grid){
   int i, j;

   for(i = 0; i < Grid->N; i++){
       for(j = 0; j < Grid->M; j++){
           free(Grid->adj[i][j]);
       }
       free(Grid->adj[i]);
   }

   free(Grid->adj);
   free(Grid);
}
```

Comment: Note that [Three-Star Programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) is not a compliment.  It may be necessary, but you should be extremely careful.

Comment: The line `Grid->adj = malloc(N * sizeof(char ***));` contains three stars where two would be appropriate.  Fortunately for you, `sizeof(char ***) == sizeof(char **)` so it doesn't show itself as a problem — except in the thought process.  `Grid->adj = malloc(N * sizeof(Grid->adj[0]))` might be an appropriate way of rephrasing it (or use `*Grid->adj` if you prefer).  One problem is that you're adding one star too many in the subsequent allocations too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you `malloc` memory is incorrect, proper ways should be:

```
TGrid* emptyGrid(int N, int M){
   int i,j;

   TGrid *Grid = malloc(sizeof(TGrid));
   Grid->N = N;
   Grid->M = M;
   Grid->adj = malloc(N * sizeof(char **));

   for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
       Grid->adj[i] = malloc(M * sizeof(char *));
       for(j = 0; j < M; j++){
           Grid->adj[i][j] = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
       }
   }
   return Grid;
}
```

Note that, `Grid->adj[i][j]` always points to array of 10 char, you can use this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Grid{
    int N;
    int M;
    char (**adj)[10];
  }TGrid;

  TGrid* emptyGrid(int N, int M){
   int i;

   TGrid *Grid = malloc(sizeof(TGrid));
   Grid->N = N;
   Grid->M = M;
   Grid->adj = malloc(N * sizeof(char (*)[10]));

   for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
       Grid->adj[i] = malloc(M * sizeof(char[10]));
   }
   return Grid;
}


void freeGrid(TGrid *Grid){
   int i;

   for(i = 0; i < Grid->N; i++){
       free(Grid->adj[i]);
   }

   free(Grid->adj);
   free(Grid);
}

int main() {
    TGrid* t = emptyGrid(2,3);
    freeGrid(t);
    return 0;
}
```

However, since `free` receives a `void*` parameter, there must be something else in your code.

Comment: sure, but i don't think he is leaking anything.  I ran it in valgrind and it doesn't complain.

Comment: Yep. You beat me to it Danh. A 2-dimensional array only needs 2 pointers.

Comment: @MK. And Sure, `free` receive a `void*`, he shouldn't leak anything

Comment: @Addison Actually he needs to use `Grid->adj[i][j]` point to an array of 10 char

Comment: @Danh we agree?

Comment: @Addison No, he wants a 3 dimensions array

Comment: @Danh, Yes, but you only need to malloc 2 pointers (line 7), and OP said `I have this struct called Grid that holds a 2D array of strings`. I agree this is a 3D array of characters, but phrasing it for OP to understand, it's a 2D array of strings.

Answer (score 2):

The general structure of your code is fine, but the types under `sizeof` are wrong. The general idiom for `malloc`-ing memory looks as follows

```
T *p = malloc(N * sizeof *p);
```

or, equivalently

```
T *p = malloc(N * sizeof(T));
```

Note that in the latter (type-based) variant there's one less asterisk under `sizeof` than there's is in the recipient pointer type.

That's exactly how it should be in your case as well

```
Grid->adj = malloc(N * sizeof(char **));
/* Since `Grid->adj` is `char ***`, you should have `char **` under `sizeof` */
...
  Grid->adj[i] = malloc(M * sizeof(char *));
  /* Since `Grid->adj[i]` is `char **`, you should have `char *` under `sizeof` */
  ...
    Grid->adj[i][j] = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    /* Since `Grid->adj[i][j]` is `char *`, you should have `char` under `sizeof` */
```

If that's not what you need, then there must be something wrong with your types. There's no way to say without knowing your intent.

(And I would suggest you use the first approach to specifying `sizeof` under `malloc` - use expressions, not types. That way you won't have to count asterisks.)

However, in real life this specific error would typically only result in over-allocated memory. No out-of-bound access or memory leaks should occur. If valgrind reports such errors, there must be something else at work here as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to see where the problem is since you haven't posted the code that uses the functions.

I want to point out that the calls to `malloc` need to be changed.

You have:

```
Grid->adj = malloc(N * sizeof(char ***));

for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
   Grid->adj[i] = malloc(M * sizeof(char **));
   for(j = 0; j < M; j++){
       Grid->adj[i][j] = malloc(10 * sizeof(char *));
   }
}
```

Those calls need to be changed to:

```
Grid->adj = malloc(N * sizeof(char **));

for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
   Grid->adj[i] = malloc(M * sizeof(char *));
   for(j = 0; j < M; j++){
       Grid->adj[i][j] = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
   }
}
```

You can avoid such errors by using a coding style as follows:

```
Grid->adj = malloc(N * sizeof(*(Grid->adj)));

for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
   Grid->adj[i] = malloc(M * sizeof(*(Grid->adj[i])));
   for(j = 0; j < M; j++){
       Grid->adj[i][j] = malloc(10 * sizeof(*(Grid->adj[i][j])));
   }
}
```

A simpler case that uses the same style:

```
char* cp = malloc(10*sizeof(*cp));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not allocating arrays, you are allocating pointer-based look-up tables. The only reason for doing so is if you wish the individual dimensions to have different lengths (such as in an array of strings). If you don't need that, you should never use pointer-to-pointer tables since they are slow, error-prone and needlessly complex.

To allocate an actual 3D array, you would do like this:

```
char (*array)[Y][Z] = malloc ( sizeof(char[X][Y][Z] );
...
free(array);
```

To allocate an array of strings, you would do like this:

```
char** lookup = malloc ( sizeof( char*[N] ) );
for(size_t i=0; i<N; i++)
{
  lookup[i] = ...; // assign pointers to strings
}
...
free(lookup);
```

As a rule of thumb, whenever your program contains more than two levels of indirection, the program design is most likely bad.